# How to edit the data in CK editor that comes from API?

Tags: ckeditor

I post the data in API and want to edit this data after getting from API. when I try to edit the data it gives me the following error:

CKEditorError: datacontroller-set-non-existent-root: Attempting to set data on a non-existing root. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-datacontroller-set-non-existent-root

```
<CKEditor
              editor={ClassicEditor}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              data={html}
            ></CKEditor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dummy solution for now, I don't know what is the proper reason of that:

Create one variable:

```js
let a = "";
```

Replace the content of the variable `a` with the your content coming from the API
and parse it with `htmlparser`:

```js
let data = a.replace("", htmlparser(/*data coming from your api*/))
```